# Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, python-2.x, python-module

The official support for python2 ended a few months ago , but I need it to run one of my programs and also it has been removed from the ubuntu 20.04 repository.So I wanted to compile and install python2 myself.But in the closing stages of the `make all`(in fact in `setup.py build`) , it prints the following error :

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _sqlite3           _ssl            
_tkinter           bsddb185           bz2             
dbm                dl                 gdbm            
imageop            readline           sunaudiodev     
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

I don't care about some modules like `readline` or `_tkinter` but I need `_ssl`.It's not possible to install that via `pip`.
I installed `libssl-dev` from the repository but then the following error occurred beside those after re-building:

```
Failed to build these modules:
_hashlib           _ssl
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I've the exact same issue when trying to compile python 2.7.18 from source code under Ubuntu 18.0.4. any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I would rather use a docker image for [Python2](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) than try to compile it; might be overkill for some but for me it's the easier and cleaner way.

For example if you have a `project` folder, containing at least `project.py` and `requirements.txt` you can use the following `Dockerfile` (in the same folder as `project`):

```
FROM python:2.7-slim-buster

COPY /project /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

CMD [ "python", "project.py" ]
```

Build it with `docker build -t project .`

Run it with `docker run -it --rm --name project_run project`

Depending on how complex your application is you can also try to bring it up to date so it will run on Python 3 (there are also automated tools to help you with this).

Comment: Although not a solution for the module building problem , but indeed a nice alternative.Thanks.